# Select grouped result

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have a List of clients

```
public class Client
{
    public string ClientID { get; set; } // Client
    public decimal Amount { get; set; } // Sales $
}
```

e.g. with following data

```
ClientID | Amount
---------+-------
000021354|   200
000021353|   300
000021353|   400
000021352|   100
000021351|   200
000021350|   100
```

Code:

```
List<Client> cList = new List<Client>();
cList.Add(new Client() { ClientID = "000021354", Amount = 200 });
cList.Add(new Client() { ClientID = "000021353", Amount = 300 });
cList.Add(new Client() { ClientID = "000021353", Amount = 400 });
cList.Add(new Client() { ClientID = "000021352", Amount = 100 });
cList.Add(new Client() { ClientID = "000021351", Amount = 200 });
cList.Add(new Client() { ClientID = "000021350", Amount = 100 });
```

I want it to be grouped by ClientID and `Sum` up the sales. The top 3 (clients with most sales) should be selected - the rest should be grouped int "others"

So the result should be:

```
ClientID | Amount
---------+-------
000021353|   700 #1 (300 + 400)
000021354|   200 #2
000021351|   200 #3
others   |   200 // (000021352 + 000021350)
```

But somehow my grouping doesn't work:

```
var Grouped = cList.GroupBy(x => x.ClientID)
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Select( y=> y.Amount).Sum())
                .Select(x => x).Take(3); //how to add "others" ?
```

Comment: What are the results you are currently getting, if any?

Comment: "But somehow my grouping doesn't work" What do you mean? Do you get a compiler error? A run-time exception? Unexpected results?

Comment: @Rik - Unexpected results and i don't know how to add that "others"

Comment: @Byyo What do you mean by "The top 3"? The first results? The highest amount? The highest amount per client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go with something like this

```
var grouped = a.GroupBy(x => x.ClientID, y => y.Amount)
               .Select(x => new Client { ClientID = x.Key, Amount = x.Sum() })
               .OrderByDescending(x => x.Amount);

var final = grouped.Take(3).ToList();
final.Add(new Client { ClientID = "Others", Amount = grouped.Skip(3).Sum(x => x.Amount) });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var grouped = cList.GroupBy(x => x.ClientID)
                   .Select(g => new { Id = g.Key, TotalAmount = g.Sum(c => c.Amount)})
                   .OrderByDescending(x => x.TotalAmount);

var result = grouped.Take(3).ToList();
result.Add(new {Id = "others", TotalAmount = grouped.Skip(3).Sum(x => x.TotalAmount)});
```

Answer (score 1):

To do what you need I think you are going to need to do the group first and later create the result you are expecting.

```
var query=cList.GroupBy(x => x.ClientID)
               .Select(g=>new{UserId=g.Key, Amount=g.Sum(y=>y.Amount)})
               .OrderByDescending(e=>e.Amount);

var result= query.Take(3).Concat(new[]{new {UserId="others", Amount=query.Skip(3).Sum(e=>e.Amount)}});
```

PS: I use an anonymous type to project my query because I thought it was linq to entities, but if you are working with a list like you show above, you can project over your `Client` class

Comment: @Byyo, just a FYI, with this approach your query is not going to be materialized until you iterate over the result or you call `ToList` extension method, that is in case you want to keep deferred execution

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
        var Grouped = (from Group in (from client in clients
                                      group client by client.Id into clientGroup
                                      select new { Id = clientGroup.Key, Sum = clientGroup.Sum(cc => cc.Amount) })
                       orderby Group.Sum descending
                       select Group).Take(3).ToList(); ;
        var Top3 = Grouped.Take(3).ToList();
        var Others = Grouped.Skip(3).ToList();
```

if you want "others" as a list. Otherwise, change the last line to:

```
var Others = Grouped.Skip(3).Sum(g => g.Sum);
```

to get the sum of the others.

Answer (score 0):

Remember `GroupBy` will return a grouping not a list of `Client`. You can easily project the grouping back into a list, in this case using an anonymous object.

```
var clients = cList.GroupBy(x => x.ClientID)
                     .Select(x => new { ClientID = x.Key, AmountTotal = x.Sum(c => c.Amount) })
                     .OrderByDescending(x => x.AmountTotal);

var topThree = clients.Take(3);
var others = clients.Except(topThree);
```